# What's the difference between these two methods of getting the system's temp dir?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

[From api.flutter.dev:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html)

```
var systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
```

[From this plugin:](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;
```

Comment: I think that the normal user can't tell you much more other than what's written down in their API reference...have you read that?

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.systemTemp` is on iOS at least the more correct path than using path_provider's `getTemporaryDirectory()` function!

They are very different in how they function.

The `Directory.systemTemp;` variable returns the `/tmp` folder for iOS for instance whereas the `getTemporaryDirectory()` function returns the `/Library/Caches` value.

If you tried natively in Swift on iOS to get the temporary directory using this code

```swift
print(FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory)
```

You would get the `/tmp/` function, which is what the `Directory.systemTemp` variable returns so this should be the way to go.